# AngularJS: Returning a promise in directive template function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, websocket, angularjs-directive

As the title already says, I'd like to return a promise in the directive template function i.e.:

```
angular.module('someModule', [])
  //...
  .directive('someDirective', function() {
    return {
      //...
      restrict: 'E',
      template: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        //Some Async function which will call deferred.resolve

        return deferred.promise; //Promise not supported by template property
      }
    };
  });
```

Since the template property doesn't support this, is there any (simple) way to "emulate" that?

It looks like directive resolve is my best bet, but I'm having a hard time coming up with a nice way to apply the template loaded from a WebSocket in the resolve method.

My goal is to use a single WebSocket connection for all communication.

Comment: how about controller property?

Comment: Yeah that is an option. But if I understand correctly, going that route would require me to specify a dummy template with something like ng-include in it, and then compile the template gotten from the websocket call and set it to the src variable used in ng-include. I'm hoping for a less roundabout way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try another approach:

```
app.run(function($templateCache, myTemplateLoader) {
    myTemplateLoader.load('templateName').then(function(content) {
        $templateCache.put('templateName', content);
    });
});
```

And now you can simply use the `templateUrl` property in your directives:

```
app.directive('someDirective', function() {
    return {
        // ...
        templateUrl: 'templateName'
    };
});
```

Comment: $templateCache looks promising.  But I'm having trouble getting your code to work.  Is 'myTemplateLoader' a custom service which I have to create myself which has a load method which returns promises? And in the directive shouldn't that be 'templateUrl' instead of 'template'?   Otherwise I don't understand how angular is able to know that 'templateName' should be treated as a template request instead of just being the template string.  And if I got it to work, that would load all templates (in the run block) immediately, right?

Comment: @Arokh Yes, `myTemplateLoader` implementation is up to you since you've said you want to use WebSocket (I'm not aware of built-in support for it). And yes, it should be `templateUrl` instead of `template`. My bad. I'll fix the answer.

Comment: @Arokh Answering your last question, yes, this way all templates would be pre-loaded and cached in the `run` block. I see that it may or may not be desirable.

Comment: I'll take this as the answer since it doesn't require me to compile the template gotten from the websocket afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

In the resolve return the template and please follow dan wahlin's dynamic loading controller example and do the same like routeResolver.resolve function for your directive

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/05/22/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs.aspx

Please let me know if it does not work i will create plunker and update it

Comment: Mhh, that article reads like it tackles a different problem. In case I've misunderstood, where could I place the async (websocket) call to load the template?